# What is an invalid LiveChatMessage text?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a bot that will insert messages into my chat.  Coolio.  Code works and I can insert messages.  However, messages with a URL inside them won't show up because youtube api returns a 400.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert) a 400 means "Message text is not valid" but does not tell me what makes a message invalid.

I can't find any documentation stating what makes a message "Invalid"

So, what makes a text message invalid?